# Help Getting GPU and the attached graphic monitor device information using CUDA or Open CL from Mathematica

Tags: graphics, cudalink, gpu, opencllink

My project is in the area of image analysis.  I am analyzing the output of a projector attached to the computer running W Mathematica. Therefore, I will like to get information of the graphical device (The projector) and the GPU handling the Projector device.

I need help determining best choice to get the information of the GPU card and any graphical monitor attached to this GPU card. I am most interested on the resolution capability of the computer monitor and relation to the GPU using the CUDALink or OpenCL or any other functionality within Mathematica.

My objective is to create a Image matrix controlling the output of every possible pixel output generated from the output graphical device projector.

Please, let me know which way I am best getting this information done (CUDALink, OpenCL , or any other Expression)

Comment: CUDA and OpenCL have nothing do to with graphics or computer displays.  They are a means of using your graphics card to do something else than graphics.  To get hardware info, check `SystemInformation[]`.  It gives you a GUI by default, but it can also give you specific information in structured form.